# Can't compile a c project i got from my teacher. (mac)

Tags: c, macos

So i got a makefile and when i run that i get this:

```
gcc -Wall -g -L. -DSTUDENT_MODE=1 -o lab2 lab2.c lab2_funcs.c advfuncs.o -lm
ld: warning: ignoring file advfuncs.o, file was built for unsupported file format ( 0x7F 0x45 0x4C 0x46 0x02 0x01 0x01 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 ) which is not the architecture being linked (x86_64): advfuncs.o
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "__array", referenced from:
      _main in lab2-bdc822.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [all] Error 1
```

The makefile looks like this:

```
PROGRAM=lab2
SOURCES=lab2.c lab2_funcs.c
CFLAGS=-Wall -g -L.

all: $(SOURCES)
    gcc $(CFLAGS) -DSTUDENT_MODE=1 -o $(PROGRAM) $(SOURCES) advfuncs.o -lm

#teacher: $(SOURCES)
#   gcc $(CFLAGS) -DSTUDENT_MODE=0 -c advfuncs.c
#   gcc $(CFLAGS) -o $(PROGRAM) $(SOURCES) advfuncs.o -lm

clean:
    \rm -f lab2 lab2_funcs.o
```

I tried running this on eclipse on my windows machine but i get other errors. I even got a complete compiled version of the project by the teacher but i cant seem to run that either, i just get an error that i cant that binary file.

Comment: I assume you don't have the source for the `advfuncs.o` file? Then there's really nothing we can do to help you. If your teacher doesn't provide an object file for your system you have to think of some other way to build your program (virtual machine perhaps?).

Comment: It looks like `advfuncs.o` was not compiled for your platform. Do you have the source for that?

Comment: My psychic powers tell me that your teacher gave you advfuncs.o as a precompiled **Linux** file.  The `__array` variable is defined there.  Ask your teacher to give your source to advfuncs or to precompile a mac build for you.

Comment: I have the advfuncs.o files. yes i got several, i tried all of them and none of them worked. I'll ask him to compile one for macs i guess

Comment: What do you mean by "I got several"? How were those files labeled for the particular platform?

Comment: advfuncs.o
advfuncs32.o
advfuncs64.o
advfuncs-win64.o

I just changed the the last command in the make file to all of those and none worked

Comment: You probably have to deal with your teacher for this.

Comment: Yeah i realised that, i tried to not include the .o file and commented away the only function depending on it and the make file compiled just fine. so I'm gonna talk to him.